# Test for text on a page

Tags: node.js, playwright

Very basic question but I can't figure it out.

How do I test for the existence of a piece of text on a page?

e.g. does the word "mouse" exist on this page? I'm using playwright and node.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via [page.waitForSelector()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector). Example:

```
await page.waitForSelector('text=mouse')
```

See on [playwright.dev](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#text-selector) for the full documentation and how you can use the text selectors in other scenarios.